# Restricting parameters to defined types in Scala

Tags: scala, types

I'd like to be able to wrap objects in a container in Scala to support an AST type language I'm developing. Namely, all containers will have equality and some containers will have the more expansive boolean comparators (`>=`, `>`, `<`, `<=`). The AST will support the following types:

`Int`, `BigDecimal`, `String`, `LocalDate`, `Some(Int)`, `Some(BigDecimal)`, `Some(String)`, `Some(LocalDate)` and `Set` of any of the *singular* above types, i.e., `Set[Int]`, but not `Set[AnyVal]`.

I have this set up:

```
sealed trait Containable

// This trait will contain those types that can be subject to 
// boolean comparison. Such as Date, BigDecimal, Int
// How can I restrict the value to these types?
sealed trait ContainableComparable extends Containable

// How can I restrict this to only Int, BigDecimal types?
// This should probably contain some sort of val numeric: ???
// But because BigDecimal is from scala.math and is not a true primitive 
// (doesn't inherit from AnyVal), not sure how to limit this to a 
// numeric value
sealed trait ContainableNumeric extends ContainableComparable

final case class ContainableInt(int: Int) extends ContainableNumeric
final case class ContainableBigDecimal(bd: BigDecimal) extends ContainableNumeric
final case class ContainableString(str: String) extends Containable
final case class ContainableBoolean(bool: Boolean) extends Containable
final case class ContainableDate(date: LocalDate) extends Containable

sealed trait Container {
  val value: Containable
}

case class ContainerBoolean(value: ContainableBoolean) extends Container
case class ContainerNumeric(value: ContainableNumeric) extends Container
case class ContainerDate(value: ContainableDate) extends Container
case class ContainerString(value: ContainableString) extends Container

sealed trait ContainerSet {
  val values: Set[Containable]
}

object ContainerSet {
  def apply[T <: Containable](set: Set[T]): ContainerSet[Containable] = {
      set apply {
        case s: Set[ContainableInt] => ContainerSet[ContainableInt](s.map(ContainerNumeric.apply))
        case s: Set[ContainableBigDecimal] => ContainerSet[ContainableBigDecimal](s.map(ContainerNumeric.apply))
        case s: Set[ContainableString] => ContainerSet[ContainableString](s.map(ContainerString.apply))
        case s: Set[ContainableDate] => ContainerSet[ContainbleDate](s.map(ContainerDate.apply))
      }
  }
}
```

I don't think shapeless is the right tool here. From what I understand shapeless does the "meta" of this. In other words, shapeless allows us to restrict type parameters that are objects to a certain subset of objects. Here I'm trying to restrict the type parameter of a primitive to a certain subset of primitives.

Comment: I still don't get your question. Where exactly do you want to put restriction? Now assume you can do that, how would you use that? I.e. show a hypothetical usage example of your restricted API (something you can't do with your current example code in the question)

Comment: Trying to eliminate type erasure when constructing a Container on a Set. Also, I can't restrict a numeric container to use Int and BigDecimal only so there isn't a usage example that I can currently get working in Scala right now.

Comment: I want to put the restriction on the `ContainerSet` so that a `ContainerSet` is only ever constructed using the given `Containable`s.

Comment: ? `set apply {` ?? Perhaps you mean `match`? Also, maybe you could include a code example of something that is currently possible but should be disallowed.

Comment: The only possible implementations of `ContainableNumeric` are for `Int` and `BigDecimal`, so I don't really understand why you say "I can't restrict a numeric container to use Int and BigDecimal".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, particularly it is not clear at all how `ContainableNumeric` is supposed to be used. Still I think `implicit` parameters might be the way to solve your problem. What you are trying to do looks like you want is to create a sealed [typeclass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class) just for the classes you allow and require the generic type to be constrained by that type class. Here is a simplified example of how it might look like:

```
@implicitNotFound("""Cannot find implicit value for Containable[${T}]. The type ${T} is not Containable.""")
sealed trait Containable[T] {
  def wrap(value: T): Container[T]
}

sealed trait ContainableComparable[T] extends Containable[T] with Ordering[T]

sealed trait ContainableNumeric[T] extends ContainableComparable[T]

object Containable {

  private class ContainableImpl[T] extends Containable[T] {
    override def wrap(value: T): Container[T] = new Container[T](value)(this)
  }

  private class ContainableNumericImpl[T: Numeric] extends ContainableImpl[T] with ContainableNumeric[T] {
    override def compare(x: T, y: T): Int = implicitly[Numeric[T]].compare(x, y)
  }

  private class ContainableComparableImpl[T <: Comparable[T]] extends ContainableImpl[T] with ContainableComparable[T] {

    override def compare(x: T, y: T): Int = x.compareTo(y)
  }


  implicit val containableInt: ContainableNumeric[Int] = new ContainableNumericImpl[Int]
  implicit val containableBd: ContainableNumeric[BigDecimal] = new ContainableNumericImpl[BigDecimal]

  implicit val containableString: ContainableComparable[String] = new ContainableComparableImpl[String]
  implicit val containableBool: Containable[Boolean] = new ContainableImpl[Boolean]
}


sealed case class Container[T: Containable](value: T)


sealed case class ContainerSet[T: Containable](value: Set[T])

sealed class ContainerSet2[T: Containable](value: Set[Container[T]])

object ContainerSet2 {
  def apply[T: Containable](set: Set[T]): ContainerSet2[T] = {
    new ContainerSet2(set.map(el => implicitly[Containable[T]].wrap(el)))
  }
}
```

and here is an usage example:

```
def test(): Unit = {
  val ci = Container(1)
  val cs = Container("abc")
  // val cd = Container(1.0)// fails with a compilation error

  val csi = ContainerSet(Set(1))
  val cs2i = ContainerSet2(Set(1))
  // val csd = ContainerSet(Set(1.0))// fails with a compilation error
  // val cs2d = ContainerSet2(Set(1.0))// fails with a compilation error
}
```

Since you have no example of usage of your `ContainerSet`, I provided two different possible implementations: one that wraps the whole `Set` and another that wraps each element inside the set like your original code does.

This code is probably not what you really want but it is hard to guess without usage example and it might be a step in the right direction.